# facebook like button does not work for my page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

Here is the code for the facebook like button I got from the dev page but it does not work.

the JS SDK

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And the HTML code to go in.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Whenisdryday" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Comment: You say it does not work. What happens? Have you checked the Javascript console to see if there are any errors?

Answer (score 0):

By not working I presume that you want the profile picture form the page to load in as well. I have tested your code and it loads everything you tell it to fine. Here is basic example of that will load in a profile picture as well.

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Whenisdryday" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

All I have changed is the class from fb-like to fb-like box.

You can add more by add more data-... to the div tag. Here different version that you can play around with.

```
<div id="fb-like-box" class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Whenisdryday" data-width="450px" data-height="600px" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right.
The problem is that your not LIVE. .. In other words, place the same code in your html5 file in GoDaddy or where ever it's being hosted.